# Cloudant java non-latin characters

Tags: java, couchdb, gson, cloudant

I am having a difficulty trying to use the Cloudant java client with Greek characters. Saving objects that include Strings with Greek characters seems to be working ok, as they appear correctly at the Cloudant console. Below is a minimal test case for this. The DummyObject has a String name, an _id and a _rev.

```
    String password = "xxxx";
    CloudantClient client = new CloudantClient("xx", "xxx", password);
    Database database = client.database("mydatabase", false);

    DummyClass dummyobject = new DummyClass();
    dummyobject.setName("ά έ ό ύ αβγδεζηθικλμνξ");
    Response saveResponse = database.save(dummyobject);
    String id = saveResponse.getId();
    String result=new String();
    DummyClass loaded = database.find(DummyClass.class,id);
    result = result+"Object:"+loaded.getName()+"\n"; //Prints out garbage

    result = result+"UTF-8:"+new String(loaded.getName().getBytes(),Charset.forName("utf-8"))+"\n"; //Prints most characters correct, except for some accented ones

    InputStream inputStream = database.find(id);
    DummyClass loadedFromStream = Json.fromJson(Json.parse(inputStream), DummyClass.class);
    result = result+"From Stream:"+loadedFromStream.getName(); //prints out fine

    return ok(result);
```

By retrieving the stream and using Jackson to deserialize, the output is correct, but then I'd have to implement many of the provided methods for views, bulk document manipulation etc.

Perhaps the problem is in the LightCouch library, specifically here: [CouchDbClientBase.java](https://github.com/lightcouch/LightCouch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/lightcouch/CouchDbClientBase.java#L540%20CouchDbClientBase.java), since that is the point that I have found differs between the two implementations (*get()* as object and as stream). However, I do not know how to confirm, fix or work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed at the [LightCouch library](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/master/src/main/java/org/lightcouch/CouchDbClientBase.java). Making the following change and respective changes on the code for views, fixed it.

```
return getGson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(in), classType);
```

to

```
return getGson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8")), classType);
```

Answer (score 3):

We fixed this in release 1.1.0, I think:

https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/releases/tag/1.1.0

`[FIX] Fixed handling of non-ASCII characters when the platform's default charset is not UTF-8.`